# Trying to save string into oracle database, but got Validation failed for one or more entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

I am trying to save a string into the db, the column holds this string value is VARCHAR2(400 byte), I entered a string which length is 399 in the textarea , but this will cause the issue. I am using entity framework and oracle, the character encoding in db is UTF8. 
Btw, there is another column which length is VARCHAR2(1 byte), and I entered 1 char in the front end and it works well.
Does anyone know what the issue is?

Update:
I tried to insert the same string in the oracle SQL developer, it works. So I would assume the issue is from the entity framework.

Update-2:
Checked the more details of EntityValidationErrors, found out there is another table to store the value, which is for edit record, and that column is less than 400 bytes. Problem identified, thanks you all.

Comment: If you need more characters I suggest you to use MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT. VARCHAR is not for Storage requirement it is only for how the data is retrieved from data base.

Comment: Try a little edit on your code, inserting `length(yourString)` instead of `yourString`; this should work and tell you the real length of the string you're trying to insert.